# Generic class to array of generics of same generic type

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I have a method signature like

```
public <T extends SomeClass> T[] findAll(Class<T> oClass, String condition)
```

But I'm not sure how I can create that `T[]` type from `Class<T>`. I've tried using a `Collection<T>` but I cannot cast `(T[]) collection.toArray()` and `Array.newInstance(Class<?>, int)` asks for an array class (i.e. `T[]`) already, which is of no use and redundant.

Also, obvisously, `new T[n]` does not work.

I would presume it's something easy, but I'm numb for the solution right now :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`newInstance` does not ask for an array class, it asks for the component type.  It will work fine, albeit with the usual problems with unchecked casts and generic arrays.

```
T[]  myArr = (T[]) Array.newInstance(oClass, length);
```

But why mix arrays and Generics at all?  It'll just lead to headaches.  Use something from the Collections API, like `List`.

Comment: Yes, perhaps a `Collection` like a `List` should be fine, but since I don't want the returned value to be modifiable, I prefer to have an array instead of `Collections.unmodifiableList()`

Comment: @Yanick: But you can always modify an array!  `Collections.unmodifiableList()` does a much better job of keeping your collection unmodifiable.

Comment: yes, of course, I was referring more about the `add` and `remove` methods; you can't add or remove items in an array. Replacing a value if of no concern, but point taken.

Comment: @Yanick: If you have an array (of any reference type), you can use `Arrays.asList(array)` to convert it into a fixed-lenght list. So you could use an empty Object[], wrap it into a list, cast the list to the right generic type, and then fill it (or first fill, then make list). This needs a SuppressWarning, but if the array stays in your method, it should be safe.